# VBA runtime error only sometimes shoes up: Run-time error 1004: Delete method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a code that will look at two sheets and delete a row in "Open Report" if there is a row with the same cell value in "FNDWRR".

Example if the value of H34 in sheet "FNDWRR" is the same as E19 in "Open Report", row 19 of "Open Report would be deleted.

The code worked fine for a while, and now I'm getting "Run-time error '1004': Delete method of Range class failed"

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteDupeRows()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "FNDWRR"
    Const sFirst As String = "H7"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Open Report"
    Const dFirst As String = "E12"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'Debug.Print wb.Name
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = refNonEmptyColumn(sws.Range(sFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print sws.Name, srg.Address
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refNonEmptyColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    'Debug.Print dws.Name, drg.Address
    
    ' Combine matching destination cells into a range.
    Dim crg As Range
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim dCount As Long
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)) Then
            Set crg = getCombinedRange(crg, dCell)
            dCount = dCount + 1
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    ' Delete entire rows of matching destination cells in one go.
    If crg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No duplicates found.", vbExclamation, "Dupes"
    Else
        'crg.Worksheet.Activate
        'crg.EntireRow.Select
        'Debug.Print crg.Worksheet.Name, crg.Address
        'Debug.Print crg.Worksheet.Name, crg.EntireRow.Address
        crg.EntireRow.Delete    <----------------------------------Debugging highlights this row               
        If dCount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "1 duplicate removed.", vbInformation, "Dupes"
        Else
            MsgBox dCount & " duplicates removed.", vbInformation, "Dupes"
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function refNonEmptyColumn( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "refNonEmptyColumn"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCell.Cells(1)
            Dim lCell As Range
            Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
                Set refNonEmptyColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getCombinedRange( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "getCombinedRange"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    If AddRange Is Nothing Then
        If Not BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getCombinedRange = BuiltRange
        End If
    Else
        If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
            Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
        Else
            If AddRange.Worksheet Is BuiltRange.Worksheet Then
                Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
            End If
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that my code only works when the areas being referenced are **NOT** tables